# Error: Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument type in while loop

Tags: swift

Why am I getting this error:

> Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument type '[Vetex], Vertex'

```
if var child  = extracted.child {
    var visited = [Vertex]()
    do {
        child.parent = nil
        child        = child.next
        visited.append(child)
    } while contains(visited, child) == false
}
```

Comment: First question: Are you using swift2? There is no global contains-Function but `visited.contains(...)` should work. / Second one: is Vertex from type Equatable? I think that this is needed to work with contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Vertex` class should confirm to `Equatable` protocol.

```
// Class declaration
class Vertex : Equatable
{
}

func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool
{
    // Implement your own logic here
    return lhs.yourProperty == rhs.yourProperty
}
```

This is a good tutorial : [Swift Comparison Protocols](http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/)

Answer (score 0):

That means that "contains" method  doesn't accept [Vertex],vertex.
Can you post this method.It should look like this:

```
func contains (_: [Vertex],_:Vertex) -> Bool{
 //your code

}
```